# How to get this design in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

[image: menu bar with shadow effect]

I am working on a website and i want to add a menu bar which would look something like this

Since my website has different look and also i want to change the size. I was wondering if anyone could let me know how to get this look in photoshop?

Thanks

Comment: Hi sanjeev, welcome. this question needs more detail; can you tell us specifically the effect you want. e.g. the bendy look created by the shadow (see this post  http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/52/can-i-ask-a-question-about-achieving-a-specific-effect-in-photoshop)

Comment: as a totally personal opinion: that shadow effect is awful- i don't know why everyone is using it all across the web. I should add: if you want to know why i think its 'awful' i'd be happy to answer that in another question

Comment: @Jaips - Yeah, I personally don't like that shadow effect either. Though I've never seen it before. Lucky me I guess.

Comment: The first time I saw this type of drop shadow was with Apple's iWeb when making a photo page; the shadow is intended to give the illusion of a printed photos slightly curling up at the edges (and the same could be used to give the affect of any paper object). It's a nice 3D effect in that context, but I don't think it makes much sense anywhere else, including here.

Comment: Check out the HTML5 Canvas and use the Gradients if you want scalable graphics.

Comment: This one actually isn't really realistic, because shadows tend to get sharper when close to original object. In the upper example that's not the case.

Comment: @Philip Regan - The issue is, iWeb's photos page **did** make the images look curled. Here in this example it appears as though the bar is fixed and the page itself is curling away behind, which I'm sure is at odds with the other elements on the page.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open a new Photoshop document.
2. Using the Rounded Rectangle Tool (U), drag out your desired rectangle.
3. Double click on your layer in your layers palette. The opens the Layer Styles dialog box.
4. Check the "Gradient Overlay" box.
5. Adjust the settings appropriately (Choose a subtle gradient for your effect i.e similar shades)
6. Add a stroke small, but dark stroke (Stroke is the last item in the left menu in the Layer Style menu)
7. Add a *subtle* white color dodge inner glow (e.g. size 1 px, full choke, full range, opacity ≤ 15 %)

The shadow is a little bit more complicated as it's not the default drop shadow, or even a common variant of it.

For the shadow follow these steps:

1. Duplicate the rectangle layer.
2. Add a drop shadow to the layer. Make it nice and big.
3. Click OK, closing the Layer Styles box.
4. Layer -> Layer Style -> Create Layer.
   This creates a layer for each layer effect.
5. Select the "Drop Shadow" layer.
6. Edit -> Transform -> Warp
7. Bend the corners down, and push the middle up. This will give you the same effect as the shadow in the picture does. If the shadow is too intense, simply lower the opacity. You may also paint/erase with a soft brush.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or you need me to expand on anything.

Comment: I took the liberty to add an inner glow step to your fine answer—saw no point submitting it separately.

Answer (score 0):

@sanjeev

bhai This link will help you for sure....:)

http://designreviver.com/articles/better-drop-shadows-in-photoshop/

Just do the same things with your shape...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be rendered in browser, you can use the [HTML5](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_canvas.htm) [Canvas](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_create_gradients.htm).

Otherwise, using an SVG is better for this type of stuff, IMHO.